# is it possible to move document libararies between 2 servers?

Tags: library, move, server, collection

I have written code to transfer document libraries including folder structure in c# between 2 site collections, within same site collections and between 2 web application on same farm. just wondering , if its possible to move between 2 servers.

Note: Not using template method

Answer (score 1):

I would say it depends on your code, what object model you are using and what requirements you have for your source and target libraries and data.

If you were using the SSOM and are not using an intermediate storage to move the data from library A to library B you will be out of luck, as I don't believe SSOM supports remote calls.

If you were using CSOM, I don't foresee any issues, same with Webservice calls, as they both are remote by nature.